# How does GitHub change the URL without reloading a page?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, github

Go to any GitHub [page](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap) and click on any of the directories/files and observe how the URL changes but only part of the page is updated. There's no whole page reloading.

How do I do something similar using jQuery?

Does this work on most browsers (I'm using Chrome)?

Comment: If this question gets merged with a duplicate, please retain @alex's answer. It is better than Zach's answer in the other post.

Comment: I'm reopening this since the original was deleted. It only contained a link to a blog for an answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

They use the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), or specifically, [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method).

You can use this, jQuery is not required, but there are plugins such as [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/).

This works on most browsers, namely Chrome, Safari and Firefox. IE10 and above supports this. In older IEs, you can fall back onto using the hash (`window.location.hash`).

[GitHub also blogged about this](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider).

Comment: Does it need some configuration on backend?

Answer (score 4):

Github use PJAX [(Ref)](https://github.com/blog/831-issues-2-0-the-next-generation). You may see about jquery-pjax [here](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax). Note that this feature is not covered support by all browser, there are some browser that cannot be use this benefits.