# How to create the breadcrumb and the shifting view effect similar to Github

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Clicking a breadcrumb link in github will trigger the directory view area to transition to the subdirectory . What is the best way to achieve this effect. I am using asp.net mvc , jquery, jquery ui, and a jquery layout plugin (  http://layout.jquery-dev.net/  [ui layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/)  )
Shoud I abandon the layout plugin ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does github change URL without reloading a page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591087/how-does-github-change-url-without-reloading-a-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can start by using the [unique url pattern](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Unique_URLs). To make this sound a little familiar, let's take for example twitter:

```
#searching "stackoverflow"
https://twitter.com/#!/search/stackoverflow
```

the hash part is the one after (and including) "#". using `window.location.hash` gets it for us. then use `string.replace()` to remove `#!/` and end up with:

```
search/stackoverflow
```

then if we store this value as a variable and do `string.split('/')`, which is split the value per `/`, we are returned with this:

```
array = ['search','stackoverflow'];
```

now it looks more like a breadcrumb which we can use to build. if you were in twitter, it would be more like:

```
site / search / stackoverflow
```

and for each breadcrumb link, just append further. if you have segmented urls, it's pretty easy to build the links:

```
site                      = mysite.com
site/search               = mysite.com/search
site/search/stackoverflow = mysite.com/search/stackoverflow
```

---

for the sliding part, you need to pick up the "onhashchange" event which detects the changes to the value of the hash. The event always happens when you click a link that has `href="#somevalue"` - note the href having "#". you also notice that the page does not go anywhere (that's where AJAX magic comes to play later).

for modern browsers, you can detect hashchange using jQuery or plain JS:

```
$(window).on('hashchange',function(){
    //do whatever you want when the hash changes
});

//or

window.onhashchange = function(){
    //do whatever you want when the hash changes
}
```

for older browsers, you have to set a timer that checks the previous vs current value of the `window.location.hash`

```
(function timer(prevHash){
    var currentHash = window.location.hash;
    if(prevHash !== currentHash){
        //do whatever you want when the hash changes
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        timer(currentHash);
    },1000);
}();
```

---

the sliding effect can be achieved using jQuery `.animate()`. you can load the new page via AJAX (depending on the page you determined using the parsed hash), append the loaded page, slide the contents, and boom! you are done. It's pretty easy for everyone to make if they know the gears that make the clock turn.