# Seamless Hyperlinks (?)

Tags: javascript, html, web, responsive-design

First of all, sorry for the bad terminology used here. I have no clues on what the thing I try to explain is called. Let me try:

I recently see a lot of nice websites being build with a "seamless hyperlink" system -- when hyperlinks are clicked it does not visit a url but it somehow switches to it seamlessly (no page reloading or such). Some websites do this in such a good way that it looks like the website is done as a single piece such as the flash websites of early 2000's.

I'm aware of this topic:

Here is an example to explain what I mean:
http://www.thenerodesign.com/

I'm aware of this thread:
[How does GitHub change the URL without reloading a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591087/how-does-github-change-the-url-without-reloading-a-page)

What I'm asking here is not pnly the "change of the url" part ut also "loading of the clicked content" part. I can modify the address bar, no problems with that. However, I have no clues on how to display different websites when a certain url is visited, or how to load a clicked hyperlink in a seamless way like the website example above.

Therefore, the question exceeds the "history api"

If my question is unclear please let me know so that I can modify it accordingly to make it more clear.

Thank you.

Comment: *also "loading of the clicked content" part* — That's a technique known as "ajax". It's so common that's its considered a basic part of modern web development these days. There are loads of tutorials.

Comment: "how to display different websites when a certain url is visited" — You set up your server to return the content for the URL when the URL is requested. That's how URLs work.